# Probability of winning in a game with throws of several two-colour dice

Tags: combinatorics

My kids are playing a board game(*) whose rules have the following as their core. Paul throws 3 or 4 dice, each with 6 faces, 4 of which are red and 2 of which are purple. Alice does the same. Paul wins if the number of red faces in his throw is larger than the number of purple faces in Alice's throw. I am trying to compute the probability that Paul wins. I guessed that the probability to get $n$ red faces in a throw of $d$ dice is

$$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}d\\n\end{pmatrix}4^n 2^{d-n}}{6^d},$$

from which it is easy to compute the probabilities I want. But my combinatorials are weak! Is that correct? If so, what would be the simplest demonstration?

(*) based on the Miraculous TV series for the record!

Comment: I think you meant $\begin{pmatrix}d\\n\end{pmatrix}$, otherwise it is correct. What do you mean by demonstration?

Comment: Yes, sorry, corrected. I always get confused with this notation. As for the demonstration, I basically numbered each face and considered all combinations: this is kinda wasteful since so many are equivalent with only two colours. I was wondering whether there is a better way…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment this is true, and you can achieve the same result by:

Choose $n$ out of $d$ dice, on each of the $n$ dice you need a red face which has a probability of $2/3$ and on any other die you need a purple face which has a probability of $1/3$. Overall the probability is $$\binom{d}{n}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{d-n}$$